# AS/400 Command call - JT400 (Java)

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, jt400

01) I was trying to get IBM/AS400 Serial no using command call method. code is working coz it's nothing given any error or exception. i thing there is something missing. help me to correct it.

02) is there is any way to get AS/400 serial no using jt400 (java). i found `getSerialNum()` method. but `com.ibm.cics.server.CertificateInfo` import is give exception. also help me to correct it **(if anyone can tell me how to get serial no using `getSerialNum()` method it's really helpful for me)**

Thank in advance!

#### My command call code :

```
AS400 system = new AS400();
CommandCall command = new CommandCall(system);
try
{
    // Run the command "DSPSYSVAL" and parameter value for "SYSVAL" is "QSRLNBR"
    if (command.run("DSPSYSVAL QSRLNBR") != true)
    {
        // Note that there was an error.
        System.out.println("Command failed!");
    }else{

           // Show the messages (returned whether or not there was an error.)
    AS400Message[] messagelist = command.getMessageList();
    for (int i = 0; i < messagelist.length; ++i)
    {
        // Show each message.
        System.out.println(messagelist[i].getText());
    }

    }

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Command " + command.getCommand() + " issued an exception!");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
// Done with the system.
System.out.println("End!");
system.disconnectService(AS400.COMMAND);
```

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that CICS is being run on your IBM i system.

Comment: To clarify why this does not work: IBM i commands don't output their results to stdout.  If the command is OUTPUT(*), the output is directed to a 5250 terminal.  If the output is OUTPUT(*PRINT) the output is directed to a printer (spooled file).  So the *nix technique of run a command, read the results won't work.  The IBM i way to consume a command's output is to use an API and get the results in a memory structure.

Comment: Is this for license enforcement?

Comment: @BuckCalabro Could one execute the command with OTUPUT(*PRINT) and the read the spooled file?

Comment: Yes, one can certainly do that.  Be aware that printed output can change from release to release, and even across PTF levels.  Finding the serial number on line 7, columns 18 - 24 on 7.2 is no guarantee that it will be in the same place in earlier (or later) versions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the [SystemValue](http://javadoc.midrange.com/jtopen/com/ibm/as400/access/SystemValue.html) class.

Comment: can i get serial no using systemvalue class ?

Comment: Yes.  The system value you want is QSRLNBR

Comment: Thanks sir. it's worked!!!!! Thanks!! hurry !! :D. do you know sir, you answered my every as400 based questions. u are like my AS400 n JT400 Teacher. Thank you so much sir :)